# Prove that any orthogonal matrix is product of Householder reflections and diagonal matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, orthogonal-matrices, reflection

> Prove that any $n \times n$ orthogonal matrix $A$ is a product of $n-1$ Householder reflections and diagonal matrices of $1$ except at one diagonal that is $-1$ (i.e. reflections about $\mbox{span}\{e_j\}^\bot$ for some $j$).

There is a hint that asks "what can be said about an upper triangular matrix that is orthogonal?" I know that an upper triangular matrix that is orthogonal is a diagonal matrix, but am unsure as to how this helps with the proof.

Comment: Do you have any theorems at your disposal?  I think the hint is referring to one.  

This has a similar flavor of Gram-Schmidt in my opinion.

Comment: What happens if you compute a QR decomposition of $A$ using Householder reflections?

Comment: You can do induction on dimension. For $n=1$, every orthogonal matrix is just $\pm 1$. For $n = 2$, there are either two real eigenvalues (necessarily $\pm 1$), or there are no real eigenvalues and the orthogonal matrix is a rotation - figure out that a 2D rotation is always doable in 2 reflections. Now for $n > 2$, determine that there is always an invariant proper subspace $V \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ for the orthogonal matrix, and check that $V^\perp$ is also invariant, and reduce to the case of smaller $n$.